# open links in safari not uiwebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

i try to open links from my local html but i don't know what is wrong in my code. I added UIWebViewDelegate to the class and the delegate to the View.

```
class TableWebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var infoWebView: UIWebView!

var htmlName:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.infoWebView.delegate = self
    self.loadHtmltoWebview(htmlName)


    self.infoWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.infoWebView.opaque = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadHtmltoWebview(name: String) {
    let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: "html")
    let url = NSURL(string: htmlFile!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    infoWebView.loadRequest(request)

}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {


    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
        print(request.URL)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

can anybody help me? Thanks!

edit: print(request.URL) is shown in the output, so he jumps into the function, but safari don't open

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in Xcode and there's no problem. What problem are you facing? Any message in the log?

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)` won't be executed, because you've put it an a comment. Or is this intended?

Comment: i put it in a comment for testing reasons. Nothing happen if ja click the link so openURL won't be executed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `UIWebViews` delegate property in `IB` is connected to your `ViewController`. Otherwise the method you implemented will never be called. Go to the outlets pane on `IB` for the `WebView` and connect the delegate outlet with your `ViewController` that implements the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.